# Any Java class available for status based communication (boolean and message) between classes

Tags: java

I have a situtation where I have to make a login request to a service class from controller and in login there could be multiple scenarios for not successful login, so I need an object to return from login method which holds one boolean and one string, boolean tells successful or not and message will tell why not so I can show it to user.

So, basically `AuthController` gets a request for log in a user and it passes the request to

```
AuthService.doLogin(String username, String password)
```

I want this `doLogin` to return a class object which holds one String and one boolean atleast to tell my controller what happened and why. Is there any class available in Java API for such a purpose?

Comment: Why not just create a LoginResponse class with attributes: boolean success; String message;

Comment: I am already doing that. I was just thinking if any such class available in java API because to me it seems like a general issue everyone might face with one thing or other.

Comment: There's none in the standard API. I have created a `Pair<A,B>` class (similar to `C++`) for such cases that I use in my own code, but dependending on who uses your code, a special `LoginResponse` class might be the better choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There aren't any Java classes available for this specific scenario, and I doubt they'll ever add classes for these types of specific use cases.

You can however create a LoginResponse class and return this class:

```
Class LoginResponse
{
    private boolean success;
    private String message;
    public void setSuccessful(){ ... };
    public void setUnsuccessful(){...};
    public void setMessage(String msg){ ... }
    public String getMessage(){ ... }
}
```

Or you can just create a class with public attributes and remove the need for the methods:

```
Class LoginResponse
{
    public boolean success;
    public String message;
}
```

If you have a fixed set of scenarios, you can create a [Java Enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html):

```
public enum LoginResponse
{

    WRONG_PASSWORD("Wrong Password", false),
    WRONG_USERNAME("Wrong Username", false),
    SUCCESS("Successfully logged in.", true);

    private String message;
    private boolean success;

    private LoginResponse(String message, boolean success)
    {
        this.message = message ;
        this.success = success;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return this.success + ": " + this.message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect, using enum fits best.